# Is there a way to make this move in a circle in stead of a square?

Tags: javascript

I'm just playing around with canvas and I'm trying to make it move in a circle instead of a sqaure, is that possible? If it is, how?

This is what I have so far and I don't know how to make it move in a circle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>derp</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    var height = 500;
    var width = 800;
    var radius = 100;
    var x = 100;
    var y = 100;
    var xass = 0;

    function draw(){
        if(x == 100 && y == 100){
            xass = 0
        }
        if(x == 700 && y == 100){
            xass = 1
        }
        if(x == 700 && y == 400){
            xass = 2
        }
         if(x == 100 && y == 400){
            xass = 3
        }
        if( xass == 0){
            x++
        }
        else if(xass == 1){
            y++
        }
        else if(xass == 2){
            x--
        }
        else if(xass == 3){
            y--
        }

        var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(400,250);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(400,250,15,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
</script>

<style>
    canvas {
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           display: block;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i created a working example in JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kup3qe5c/ for everyone like to find an answer. Notice: I DID NOT FOUND A SOLTION - JUST TRY TO IMPROVE THE QUESTION ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this https://jsfiddle.net/kup3qe5c/2/ i just made use of a circle function (math)

```
var height = 500;
var width = 800;
var radius = 150;
var x,y;

var step = 2*Math.PI/20;
var h = width/2; 
var k = height/2;

var theta = 0;

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function draw(){
    theta += step
    x = h + radius*Math.cos(theta);
    y = k - radius*Math.sin(theta);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(400,250);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(400,250,15,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}

setInterval(draw,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Create a rectangle shaped path with its top left point at
 // {x: 75, y: 75} and a size of {width: 75, height: 75}
var path = new Path.Rectangle({
point: [75, 75],
size: [75, 75],
strokeColor: 'black'
});

function onFrame(event) {
// Each frame, rotate the path by 3 degrees:
path.rotate(3);
 }
```

will this help

Comment: that's not excatly what I meant but still thanks for trying.
I'm trying to make it move in a wide circle what this does is make the square spin.